# Convert SQL to Lambda in C# with multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I have read multiple SQL to Lamda questions with joins etc. but i don't quiet understand, how to convert sql to lambda.

```
SELECT
    f.Name,
    v.Name
FROM
    Config AS c 
    JOIN Family AS f ON c.Family_ID = f.ID
    JOIN View AS v ON c.View_ID = v.ID
```

Comment: That SQL you posted is using the _horrible_ style of implicit `JOIN`. You **need** to first change the SQL to use explicit `JOIN`s - and then it's straightforward to convert that to Linq/EF.

Comment: Just edited my SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var result =  (from f in Family
                join c in Config on f.ID equals c.Family_ID
                join v in View on c.View_ID equals v.ID
                select new { FamilyName = f.Name, Name = v.Name });
```